# Django: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute error

Tags: python, django

I've two models in my app: the Dataset model is created when the File model is saved, but I'm having problem linking the file_uploaded field in the dataset to the File model using foreign key. To do so I'm using this:

`file_uploaded = request.file_uploaded.file,`

and I'm getting this error: `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'file_uploaded'` 
I'm not getting what I'm doing wrong considering that I can link the user without problems.

I had to change a little bit of my code to make it shorter, there may be some inconsistenciesbut, but the original one works (excepts for the error I'm getting).
Thank you all for the help

MODEL

```
class File(models.Model): 
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=250)   
    file_upload = models.FileField(upload_to=path)
    upload_date  = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)   

    def __str__(self):        
        return self.user.name + 'file'

class Dataset(models.Model):    
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_uploaded = models.OneToOneField(File, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    name_user_A = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    code_user_A = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    total_user_A = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    sd_user_A = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)

    name_user_B = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    code_user_B = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    total_user_B = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    sd_user_B = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
```

With File model it should be uploaded a csv file and then the information in the file should be saved in the Dataset model. After that I'd like to show some chart to my user so I need my File and Dataset models linked. This is my view:

VIEWS

```
def file_upload(request):
    data = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        raw_file= request.FILES
        if form.is_valid():                               
            form.instance.user = request.user.profile    
            form.instance.filename = raw_file['file_upload'].name
            form.save()  

            data = request.FILES['file_upload']             
            data = pd.read_csv(data, header=0, encoding="UTF-8")                  
      
            
            Dataset.objects.create(
                user = request.user.profile,
                file_uploaded = request.file_uploaded.file,
                name_user_A = data.iloc[0,1],
                name_user_B = data.iloc[1,1],
                [...]
                )          
            return redirect('upload_file')
        else:
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = FileForm()  
 
    context = {              
               'data': data,
               'form': form,                                      
               }
    return render(request, 'upload_file.html', context)
```

Comment: inspect `request.FILES`, you'll find the files that are uploading

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this `file_uploaded = request.FILES` but I'm getting this error `Cannot assign "<MultiValueDict: {'file_upload ': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: data.csv (application/vnd.ms-excel)>]}>": "Data.file_uploaded" must be a "File" instance` What can I do to solve this?